# Animating button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Thanks for taking a look.
I aim to create a button template in WPF similar to the "Start now" button on [this page](https://www.gov.uk/student-finance-register-login), except without the golden border on click. The effect I seek is a "3D" looking button being pushed into the page for as long as the press is held, preferably with a color change as well.

For this end I'd like to:

- Specify a rectangle in a control template
- Specify a second rectangle in front of it, slightly shifted up in relation with the first one.
- When the control is clicked, move the foreground rectangle down to cover the background rectangle.

For this I don't know how to animate just parts of an element.

**Edit:** Focused the question to one problem

**Edit:** Example button:

```
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key='3D'>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

          <Grid>
          <Border CornerRadius='5'
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
            <Rectangle Fill="Gray"/>
          </Border>
          <Border CornerRadius='5'
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
                  Margin='0,0,0,10'>
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" />
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"                              
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
        </Grid>  
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding='{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsPressed}'
        <!-- Some other conditions -->
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

      <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
              <!--Animation that moves the top rectangle down -->
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: [Wpf Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating)

Comment: Hello! I've taken a look at that already but all the example animations there are for altering only one property, or don't explain how to animate only parts of a template.

Comment: you can't alter only parts of a template. you have to re-write the template and then alter it.

Comment: I should have clarified, I plan to write a new template [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates) and specify the animation storyboard inside. Inside that rewritten template, I'd specify a rectangle in the background that doesn't move, and a rectangle in the foreground that does move. So I'd change the position property of only the  foreground rectangle.

Comment: Pick either and try, if you run into a problem post a question. This question is a bit too broad and is unlikely to be valuable for more people.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I focused the question a bit. I'm trying but I don't know how to get started with it, even after looking through a bunch of examples/documentation

Comment: I am sorry but this still isn't specific enough. Make a minimal example of what you have tried and show us the code. Also make very clear what you want the result to be. On Stack Overflow we prefer the questions to be as specific as possible in order to eliminate any guessing. E.g. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805791/problem-animating-a-wpf-button

Comment: You are right, I've pasted the xaml I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to animate the margin of the borders. Also, I had to move the triggers from Style.Triggers to ControlTemplate.Triggers to access the borders as targets.

```
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key='Circular'>
  <!--Set to true to not get any properties from the themes.-->
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

        <Grid>
          <Border x:Name='_bottom'
                  CornerRadius='5'
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
            <Rectangle Fill="Gray" />
          </Border>
          <Border x:Name='_top'
                  CornerRadius='5'
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
                  Margin='0,0,0,10'>
            <Grid>
              <Rectangle Fill="LightGray" />
              <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
        </Grid>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding='{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsPressed}'
                         Value='True' />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>

            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="_top"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                      From="0,0,0,10"
                                      To="0,10,0,0" />
                  <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="_bottom"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                      From="0,0,0,0"
                                      To="0,10,0,0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="_top"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                      From="0,10,0,0"
                                      To="0,0,0,10" />
                  <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                      Storyboard.TargetName="_bottom"
                                      Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                      From="0,10,0,0"
                                      To="0,0,0,0" />
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
          </MultiDataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>

</Style>
```